# Sorting multiarray on numeric field

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, numeric

I have an array like below. I need to sort each array on the 2 key.

```
    myarray [
     [2020] = [0 => 123, 1 => 234, 2 => 45],
     [2021] = [0 => 123, 1 => 34,  2 => 345],
     [2019] = [0 => 123, 1 => 134, 2 => 645]
    ]
```

So the results would be

```
     [2020] = 
      45
      123
      234
     [2021] = 
      34
      123
      345
     [2019] = 
      123
      134
      645]
```

I've tried

```
    array_multisort( array_column($myarray, $myarray[2]), SORT_ASC, $myarray );
```

and

```
    usort($myarray, array($myarray[2], 'sort_function'));

    function sort_function($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a == $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

Neither of the above worked. Would someone please point out my mistake or the correct way to do this?

Here is a better explanation of the problem:

```
    myarray [
     [2020] = [0 => 123, 1 => 234, 2 => 357],
     [2020] = [0 => 123, 1 => 34,  2 => 157],
     [2020] = [0 => 123, 1 => 134, 2 => 257]
    ]

     [2020] = 
      157
      257         
      357
```

Comment: `sort_function` should be the first argument to `usort`, not an argument to `array()`.

Comment: the second argument to `array_column` should just be `2`, not `$myarray[2]`. You already told it which array to get the column from in the first argument.

Comment: How is your result "sorting on the 2 key"? You're sorting each array numerically, not based on a particular key.

Comment: The usort manual shows the array is the first argument. Am I not understanding it?  I tried changing myarray[2] to just 2 but it causes the final array to be just one element. The array is a list of values with the 2 key holding the total of all of them. I now see that my example wasn't structured well and have changed it to show the result for just one of the years. I do apologize for the confusion it caused.

Comment: Sorry, I got it backwards. But `sort_function` should be an argument to `usort()`, not `array()`.

Comment: Array keys have to be unique. You can't have  multiple `2020` keys.

Comment: That's not a "better explanation". It's a completely different result.

Answer (score 0):

For your second result, use:

```
$second_elements = array_column($myarray, 2);
sort($second_elements);
```

Comment: My last comment came back as deleted. Have I violated some rule in asking this question?

Comment: Your comment wasn't deleted. He deleted his answer because it was no longer correct for the question, and all the related comments go with it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm totally confused at this point. Mostly due to my posting the question incorrectly. I will keep trying variations based on what was said here and post a solution if I can find one. I do appreciate the help offered.

Comment: @Bar please close this Unclear question.  Array cannot have multiple `2020` keys in the same level.